# How to resolves "prop-types not found on request" error?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-proptypes

I'm trying to start a new ReactJS project with [material-ui Next](https://material-ui-next.com/) and [fuse-box](https://github.com/fuse-box/react-example).

I've installed all dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.27",
    "material-ui-icons": "^1.0.0-beta.17",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8"
 }
```

But I keep seeing the error: "prop-types not found on request". The breakpoint is here:

```
var _propTypes = require('prop-types');

exports['default'] = {
  jss: (0, _propTypes.shape)({...
```

Any idea what's causing this error?

---

**My code**

My App page mimics [this example provided by Material UI](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/examples/create-react-app/src/pages/index.js):

```
import * as React from "react";
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types'; 
import { Component } from "react";
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Button } from 'material-ui/Button';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isAuthenticated: true
        };
    }

    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        const { isAuthenticated } = this.state;
        return (
            <Button raised color="primary">
              Hello World
            </Button>
        );
    }
}

App.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default App;
```

This app component is rendered in my index file like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I think props types should be imported like ``import  PropTypes from 'prop-types'; `` as per https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: Tried that already but it doesn't resolve the error.

Comment: What about wiping out the node_modules directory and reinstalling everything?

Comment: Also tried that a moment ago, unfortunately doesn't help either

Comment: Maybe try packaging this up somewhere and I'll give it a crack see if it happens on my environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer from one of the creators of fusebox [here](https://github.com/fuse-box/fuse-box/issues/1014#issuecomment-355826856)

I used the wrong import statement:

```
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';
```

The correct way to do it with fusebox is:

```
import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types'
```